# Create Hardlink with golang

Tags: windows, go, hardlink

I want to create a hardlink to a file using golang.
os.Link() tells me, that windows is not supported.
Therefore i tried to use os.exec, to call "mklink.exe".

```
cmd := exec.Command("mklink.exe", "/H", hardlink_path, file_path)
err := cmd.Run()
```

However, it tells me, that it can't find mklink.exe in %PATH%.
This baffels me, since i can call it using cmd.

Next i tried to call it indirectly via cmd:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "mklink.exe", "/H", hardlink_path, file_path)
err := cmd.Run()
```

Now it does not return any error, however, it also doesn't create a hardlink.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you change the accepted answer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Golang support for native Windows hard links was added in Go 1.4. Specifically, [this commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/cf521ce64f50c4f300294d6b649f34eca87bb8a3) makes the following snippet work:

```
err := os.Link("original.txt", "link.txt")
```

Beware that not all Windows file systems support hard links. Currently [NTFS and UDF support it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee681827(v=vs.85).aspx), but FAT32, exFAT and [the newer ReFS do not](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/01/02/windows-server-2012-does-refs-replace-ntfs-when-should-i-use-it.aspx).

Full example code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {   
    err := ioutil.WriteFile("original.txt", []byte("hello world"), 0600)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }    

    err = os.Link("original.txt", "link.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a buitlin way of checking if the current file system supports hard links? Or does the `os.Link` returns an error on such file systems?

Comment: Currently (in May 2021) there does not appear to be a built-in way to check if a filesystem supports hard links. [os.Link does return an error if CreateHardLink() fails](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/0d32d9e8a8784cf3ef39c471b73e502c51085b6d/src/os/file_windows.go#L322). If you _really_ wanted to, on Windows, you could call GetVolumeInformation ([see this answer](/questions/35238933/golang-call-getvolumeinformation-winapi-function)) and check FileSystemFlags for [FILE_SUPPORTS_HARD_LINKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationw).